# React checking authentication on index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux

yesterday I changed the way I'm checking auth, I put the logic in index.js file of React application. I want to test some stuff and I'm getting an error that says localStorage is not defined although I setup mock localStorage in beforeAll block.

Is this the best way to do it or there is better way or how would I avoid this  error ?

Here is the index file:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import history from "./history";
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

import "./style.css";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.css";

import reducer from "./reducers/index";
import { getCurrentUser, logout } from "./actions/authActions/authActions";

export const store = createStore(reducer, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)));


if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {

    // decode token and get user info and expiration
    // decoded = ID
    const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('token'))
    // set User and isAuthenticated (to keep user logged in)
    store.dispatch(getCurrentUser(decoded._id))
    // check for expired token
    const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000
    if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
        // Log out the user
        store.dispatch(logout())

        // Rediret to login page if token is expired
        history.push('/login')
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Could you share the test you wrote for this? Moreover you should make sure that you get ```localStorage``` from ```window.localStorage``` if it is not mocked and in test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling localStorage method, you can:

```
if (window.localStorage && localStorage.getItem) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
        //...
    }
}

history.push('/enable-browser-storage-page');
```

This makes sure local storage is enabled by user. If it isn't, redirect that user to a page that instructs how to enable.

Additionally you can add a function that checks if local storage is available or not:

```
function lsTest(){
    var test = 'test';
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(test, test);
        localStorage.removeItem(test);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}

if(lsTest() === true){
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
        //...
    }
}else{
    history.push('/enable-browser-storage-page');
}
```